# How to get monthly average with months with no data

Tags: powerbi, dax, average

I have a table that I am trying to average records per month based on the number of months that have passed in the fiscal year.

For instance, today is the fifth month of the fiscal year and there are three records that have occurred so far. I want to show on a card visual that we have average 0.6 records per month.

```
Average Outreach per Month = 
AverageX(KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Date'[Fiscal Year Month])),IF(
Calculate(COUNT('Outreach Tracking Database'[Completed/Cancelled ])) = BLANK(),
0,
COUNT('Outreach Tracking Database'[Completed/Cancelled ])))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was to:

1. Create a measure to get the month number value from my calendar table:

> CurrentFiscalMonth =    MAXX(FILTER(ALL('Date'), 'Date'[Date] =
> TODAY()), 'Date'[Fiscal Month Number])

2. Create a second measure to divide the count of records by the value of the current fiscal month

> ```
> Average Outreach per Month = 'Outreach Tracking Database'[Outreach Count]/[CurrentFiscalMonth]
> ```

I will need to update once my data is past one year, but this is a start.